# SQL AVERAGE query - find the average of the total values of orders from column city

Tags: mysql

How can I find the average of the total values of orders from city Z?

I've only gotten this far:

```
SELECT AVG(X.TOTALVALUE) 
    FROM (SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) TOTALVALUE
    FROM ORDERS) X
```

Some of the terms I'm using might be a bit off because I've translated them from my native language to English. (And TOTALVALUE and is something that I just made up.)

I'm completely new to this. Thank you for your time.

I am trying to obtain a value something like this:

+-----------------------------------------------+ 
| Avg total value of orders from city Z  
+-----------------------------------------------+ 
| 45676546                                     
+-----------------------------------------------+

Comment: Please provide data , so that we can underszand what you want see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group the sum by order.

```
SELECT AVG(X.TOTALVALUE) 
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) TOTALVALUE
    FROM ORDERS
    GROUP BY order_id) X
```